# Silverlight detecting devices

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I would like to know if silverlight can access devices such as GPS or a form of location base device that can tell the application the returned location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227174/connecting-silverlight-to-the-local-computers-com-port), it's not feasible in 3.0 (it would require reading a COM port, and SL 3 can't do that), though there are hopes in 4.0 with an auxiliary COM object (if and where you can convince your users to install such a COM object, of course;-).