# ASP.NET How to wait for an event in a serial port

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, port, gsm, modem

I have been asked by my supervisor to develop a web application using either ASP.NET and Silverlight.NET That manages a GSM modem through COM port, I have succeeded in performing most of the required tasks except the mail notification when a message is received by the GSM modem,in fact, this task requires listening to COM port and executing an action when receiving data, I have searched for a solution but so far I only come across solutions for desktop C# applications.

Comment: I hope Silverlight doesn't let you listen to a COM port. That's a huge security risk. Why aren't you creating a windows application?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227174/connecting-silverlight-to-the-local-computers-com-port

Comment: Where is the GSM Modem connected?  Client or server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task isn't suitable for an ASP.NET application, which is, by nature, a browser-based request/response paradigm.  For a modem, you need a long-running service to listen.  I'm not sure it's a good fit for/possible with Silverlight either.

Your best option is to write either a WinForms, or better yet, Windows Service app to listen on the port and handle that functionality, while having the user-interaction happen through ASP.NET.

Your boss may or may not understand the technical differences, but it's perfectly valid to break up functionality into different executables/apps to handle different tasks.

*This is actualy the norm when you think about it.  Such a design makes this site possible.  S.O. uses a database of some sort to store data, a web server to perform logic and stream the data in a browser-readable format, and you're using a browser to view the data served by the web server.*

Using the right tool for the job is critical to good design. ASP.NET and Silverlight are the wrong tool for listenening to a COM port.

If you need to communicate with the WinForms app or Windows Service, you can expose functions via WCF and add service references to them.